# Small (SPST?) Switch to connect two independent circuits

Tags: switches

I am looking for a small push button switch (similar to: https://www.radioshack.com/collections/switches/products/rect-pushbutton) but with the capability to connect two independent circuits (without a common connection). I am using this for a Lionel model train setup.

For example, when the button is pressed, wire A is connected to wire B, and wire C is connected to wire D. However, there is no connection between circuit AB and circuit BC.  Then when the button is released, the circuits are no longer connected.

Do switches like this exist? If so, where would I be able to buy one (either in store or online)

I am new to electrical engineering so please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depending on surge currents , either a DPST Reed Relay ( 0.5~1A) or a relay <=2A or relay >2A.  These are 3 categories while the SPST switch energizes a 12V coil

Comment: This isn't so much a shopping for a "specific product" question as a "what do I call this thing so that I can try to find one" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up DPST (double-pole single-throw) switch.

**EDIT**: here's an example.
[image: DPST switch]